# iterating tensor objects in tf.data api without eager execution

Tags: python, tensorflow

data.Dataset api for converting my data into tensorflow objects and the code is

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_tensor_train, target_tensor_train)).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)

dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
```

in eager execution it is working fine with enumerate. But i like to iterator over the data without eager execution and i found some resources regarding this then i used

```
dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
iterator.get_next()
```

to iterate over the dataset.

But its giving the error

> Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.

could anybody is there to help me to solve the error

[and this is the original source code unchanged](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/nmt_with_attention/nmt_with_attention.ipynb)